# Magento, REST filter parametar 'from'?

Tags: api, magento, rest

when I call

```
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl .. )
```

I need something like this

```
$resourceUrl = "www.myaps/api/rest/orders?filter[0][attribute]=created_at&filter[0][from][0]=2013-09-04 12:53:32";
```

But this doesn't work.

I need to take all order created after specific time? But I don't know how to use 'from' in rest API :(

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
filter[0][attribute]=created_at&filter[0][from][0]=2012-09-04%2012:53:32"
```

The key is  to use "%20" between date and time